# The child already has a parent

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollbar, parent-child

I know a lot of people asked this question but I'm not sure the solution for my problem is the same.

My code is:

```
package com.example.goo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calendrier extends Activity{

    LinearLayout linear;

    TextView text;

    ScrollView SV;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SV = new ScrollView(this);          

        linear = new LinearLayout(this);
        linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("This is an example for the Bright Hub !");

        SV.addView(linear);
        linear.addView(text);
        setContentView(linear);

    }
}
```

and the error is:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: setContentView(linear); => setContentView(SV)

Comment: I also post an answer, if my comment helps you, please, accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing mistake with `setContentView` because you already added `linearLayout` in view and you are trying to add second time which cause error,

Try this:

> setContentView(SV);

Instead:

> setContentView(linear);

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I suppose you are getting this error on the last line (`setContentView(linear);`).

You first add that view `linear` to the scrollview `SV`, and then set it as the contentView.

I only know this error to come up when you add one view to another twice, but I suppose setting it as the contentview will work the same: it cannot be both a child of `SV` AND the root view.

Either set `SV` in `setContentVieW`, or don't add `linear` to that `Scrollview`

Comment: Thank's a lot, it's exactly that

Answer (score 1):

Just

`setContentView(linear);` => `setContentView(SV);`

Hope it's help